# Strange date error between Development and Production environment

Tags: java, mysql, spring, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vaadin

I have a strange date error that I can't solve for days and ask for your help.

I have developed in Java/Spring/Vaadin/Hibernate an app that creates a sport training every day by a user.
The problem is that the training date is not displayed correctly in browser.
For example, I create now a new training:

```
training.setTrainingdate(LocalDate.now());
```

On localhost shows right but online from Amazon AWS Tomcat shows it wrong date (one day before).
The MySql database is common for both cases = Amazon RDS Mysql.
My Time zone is UTC +1 (Europe/Vienna)

> 2020-02-17

but in the browser when I get the trainig from aws is show

> 2020-02-16

**What I've already checked:**

**- On AWS-RDS-MySQL Server:**

```
SELECT now();
```

> 2020-02-17 12:55:50

and

```
SELECT * FROM `mydatabase`.training;
```

> 2020-02-17

**- Elastic Beanstalk on SSH:**

```
date
```

> Mon Feb 17 11:55:50 UTC 2020

- **Log files**
- /var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out
- /var/log/tomcat8/httpd/access_log
- /var/log/tomcat8/httpd/error_log

> 2020-02-17 11:55:50.985

No matter what time I try the difference stay  one day.

Different devices and different browser same problem.

Do you have an Ideea what can be?
Thank you very much!

EDIT:

```
TimeZone.getDefault())
```

On Production Server:

> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Universal",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]

On localhost:

> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]

Comment: "but in the browser when I get the trainig from aws is show" - is that the datestring parsed through javascript ?, say `new Date()` or something, or is it the raw string from the response ?

Comment: One thing to look at is whether you have different server time zones for dev and production, i.e. the output of `TimeZone.getDefault()` in each environment.

Comment: From what you supplied it’s hard to guess. But I’d make sure, the date is stored correctly in the database (it internally usually maps to a long) and the timezone has to be correct when mapping to long and back. I think you can add a default timezone in your connection string (in the data source configuration), otherwise MySQL will pick one. Anyway, for me it sounds like your code is somehow using the server local timezone.

Comment: Where is your AWS server located? (which country)

Comment: @kscherrer US East (N. Virginia) us-east-1

Comment: @Yuvaraj G 
{"node":138,"type":"attach"},{"node":138,"type":"put","key":"tag","feat":0,"value":"template"},{"node":138,"type":"put","key":"innerHTML","feat":1,"value":"2020-02-16"},{"node":138,"type":"clear","feat":11},{"node":138,"type":"splice","feat":11,"index":0,"add":["header"]}

Comment: @Leif Åstrand 
On Localhost: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]

Comment: @ – Leif Åstrand, On Production Server: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Universal",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED

Solution:

- I add a version to maven mysql-connector-java dependency:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.48</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

I add to **spring applications.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

and add/change in the tail of spring.datasource.url to:

```
?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

PS
Many thanks to all who try to help! Specially thanks to @Leif Åstrand and @PeMa